# What are different methods of attributing sizes to sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want a method of attributing sizes with sets with the following properties (Assume AC):

1. The collection of all sizes can be well-ordered in a poset. Let us call the relation in this poset $<$.
2. If $A\subseteq B$ then the size of $A$ is at most $B$
3. Every set in $V$ is given exactly one size
4. Given a size, the collection of all sets with that size is a set*
5. There is a proper class of sets that aren't their own size.

*This is optimal but may not be possible.

Cardinality satisfies 1, 2, 3, and 5, but not 4. Lebesgue measure satisfies 1,2,4, and 5, but not 3. Order type only satisfies 1, 2 and 5.

Are there any other methods of attributing sizes with sets known? They may not even satisfy all of these properties, I just want to know. However, if it is possible, please create such a poset of sizes well-ordered by $<$.

EDIT: 
Yes there is, it's called the rank of a set. I really should've thought about this more. Because of this, I now require that the size of a set (assuming AC) is an ordinal, and if the set is finite, its size is its cardinality.

Comment: With the edit, condition 4 can't be met -- because there is no set of all singletons.

Comment: The usual way, with AxC, to size a set is to well order it and take the largest initial ordinal  that order embeds into it as the size, which is usually called the cardinality.  4 is a pipe dream.  5 is possible only in set theories that have classes and as sizes are sets, how could a proper class have a size?

Comment: I didn't say a proper class has a size. Cardinality itself satisfies 5.